# Consistently high but decreasing ping behavior on ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping

I have a ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) connected to my home router via ethernet. I had been noticing poor performance when connecting via ssh, so I ran some ping tests from the ubuntu machine. It starts high, but decreases at a strangely consistent pace. Here are the results:

```
$ ping -c 30 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.217.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=99.7 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=98.1 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=95.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=93.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=92.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=91.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=89.9 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=88.9 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=87.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=86.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=85.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=84.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=83.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=82.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=81.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=80.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=79.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=78.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=77.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=76.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=24 ttl=56 time=75.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=25 ttl=56 time=74.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=26 ttl=56 time=73.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=27 ttl=56 time=72.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=28 ttl=56 time=71.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.217.164): icmp_seq=30 ttl=56 time=61.9 ms
```

and another website to test

```
$ ping -c 30 www.apple.com 
PING e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net (23.218.213.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=99.8 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=98.1 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=95.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=7 ttl=59 time=93.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=8 ttl=59 time=92.2 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=9 ttl=59 time=91.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=10 ttl=59 time=90.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=11 ttl=59 time=88.9 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=12 ttl=59 time=88.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=13 ttl=59 time=87.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=14 ttl=59 time=86.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=15 ttl=59 time=85.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=16 ttl=59 time=84.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=17 ttl=59 time=83.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=18 ttl=59 time=82.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=19 ttl=59 time=81.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=20 ttl=59 time=80.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=21 ttl=59 time=79.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=22 ttl=59 time=78.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=23 ttl=59 time=77.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=24 ttl=59 time=75.9 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=25 ttl=59 time=74.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=26 ttl=59 time=73.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=27 ttl=59 time=72.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=28 ttl=59 time=71.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=29 ttl=59 time=70.0 ms
64 bytes from a23-218-213-175.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.218.213.175): icmp_seq=30 ttl=59 time=69.0 ms
```

Anybody know what might cause this behavior?

Update:

Pinging the router results in the same thing, so the problem must be something on the local network. Heres the report from mtr anyway:

```
                                               Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best Wrst StDev
1.|-- 192.168.1.1                               0.0%    10   74.6  81.9  74.6 100.0   9.1
2.|-- lo0-100.WASHDC-VFTTP-311.verizon-gni.net  0.0%    10   74.6  72.7   8.9  97.4  23.3
3.|-- B3311.WASHDC-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net       0.0%    10   74.5  73.6  17.9  97.3  20.6
4.|-- ???                                      100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5.|-- ???                                      100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6.|-- 0.et-10-3-0.GW13.IAD8.ALTER.NET           0.0%    10   74.2  76.0  44.8  97.0  12.7
7.|-- 204.148.79.46                            10.0%    10   74.1  76.7  53.8  96.9  11.0
8.|-- 209.85.252.121                            0.0%    10   74.1  77.6  62.9  96.8   8.3
9.|-- 209.85.143.145                           10.0%    10   74.0  78.4  71.9  96.8   7.3
10.|-- iad23s44-in-f164.1e100.net               10.0%    10   73.9  79.2  73.9  96.7   6.9
```

Not sure what 4 and 5 are.

```
$tc qdisc
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev enp9s0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Wow. You've found a (insane) problem that's visible in `ping`, perhaps you could try traceroute. The pattern of latency would be harder to check in a traceroute, but you can use ping on the intermediate routers which traceroute shows you the address of (e.g. on the way to google.com).  You might prefer the `mtr` version of traceroute, or `traceroute --icmp`. My guess is you will find the problem also occurs within the first few routers.

Comment: I notice the way that both traces are centred around whole numbers of ms, and decrease by 1ms each time, starting from 100ms, looks *very* deliberate. If that was implemented inside the network, it would almost certainly be within 0.1ms, i.e. your home router. Also you the router would need to track state. That is, in order to know how much to delay the ICMP reply to make a total delay of 100ms, you would need to remember when the ICMP request passed you originally.

Comment: You could maybe try https://nmap.org/nping/ to use protocols other than ICMP, and check whether they're affected too. If so please run it with `sudo`, so it can generate identical raw packets for each ping. I kind of guess they will be, because the behaviour is atypical... I can imagine people doing something this weird, but I can't think a reason for doing it to ICMP and not anything else, unless you're _trying_ to annoy someone.

Comment: You've mentioned a home router, but we want to ask at least if there's anything less usual about your setup - PC, router, ISP. It would be interesting to know what your router is and how you connect to your ISP (e.g. is it a cable company?).

Comment: I think the timing changes per-packet, so you might want to test faster with a lower interval.  E.g. `ping -i 0.2`.  If it works, that would make it easier to ask what happens as the artificial delay declines further.

Comment: I would definitely try starting two pings to different targets with a staggered start, e.g. wait 5 seconds before starting the second one.  I.e. do they both start at 100ms, or does the second one start at 95ms?  I'm guessing the former.

Comment: A few updates. I tried starting two pings like you said and they both start at 100. Next I tried pinging the router 192.168.1.1, and got the same thing, 100 ms and counting down by one. So the problem is somewhere between the machine and the router

Comment: ISP is Verizon, using the router that is supplied by Verizon. There really isn't anything unusual about the setup. I will run nping and see what else I can find.

Comment: Ok, so we can hypothesize lots of other people would have the same router.  Can you exclude that your Ubuntu has 1) any firewall rules or 2) non-default queuing discipline? `sudo iptables-save` dumps firewall rules, by default it should not show any rules to drop / redirect / mangle packets, I think only some line about default accept for each table.  `tc qdisc` would show each network interface, with only one line for the ethernet interface which says either `pfifo_fast` or `fq_codel`?

Comment: I forgot to ask if you noticed the SSH performance as a change, or if you think it's possible it's been like this all the time.

Comment: `sudo iptables-save ` returns nothing, so no firewall rules. I put the results of `tc qdisc` up top.

Comment: The machine hasn't been running long, so it might have been like this all the time. I noticed that right after a reboot it is often working fine, but after it has been running for while, everything slows down.

Comment: Does `ifconfig` show any errors/dropped/overrun/frame? Does `ethtool` give the expected speed/duplex mode?

Comment: ifconfig shows 234 dropped RX packets, out of 37405 total. Everything else is 0. Ethtool shows 1000 mb/s, full duplex, which is normal.